# Why does this Rust type alias need a lifetime parameter?

Tags: types, rust, type-alias

I tried the following Rust type alias:

```
type Name = String;
```

It works fine. So I tried a variant:

```
type Name = &str;
```

This failed with:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:1:17
  |
1 |     type Name = &str;
  |                 ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Why would a type alias need a lifetime parameter and how would I add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `String` owns its memory, while `&str` is a reference to a `str`. Usually you can elide lifetimes, but when a reference is stored in a `struct`, `enum`, or type alias, all lifetimes must be specified. So the correct way to write the alias is:

```
type Name<'a> = &'a str;
```

The lifetime is declared after the name of the type alias, and the lifetime of `&str` is specified to be `'a`.

Lifetimes on types can be elided in functions sometimes, which is why you can write `&str`. This also applies to other types, including type aliases. That means this is valid:

```
fn foo(s: &String) -> Name { s.as_str() }
```

The lifetime parameter on `Name` is elided here.